# How do I get rid of the JFrame within another frame?

Tags: java, swing

I will try to be really specific with my question.So I have an application in a JFrame which contains 3 buttons and each of them open another JFrame  and they are doing some animation inside.So what i have to do is close just one frame but not the main frame with it.And in this 3 frames there is SwingWorker who is processing some data,so when I close specific frame I want this application to stop and not doing in a background.

Comment: And where is your question? Do you want to know, how to stop a `SwingWorker`?

Comment: How do I close a frame and stop the application in the second one, without closing the main one?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 1):

You can add an actionListerner on the click of the button..Once the button is clicked you set the visibility of a specific frame to false the user the dispose function on that specific frame and cancel its background activities

like below

```
cancelbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            frame1.setVisible(false);
            frame1.dispose();
```